# How to migrate data from on-prem Postgres database into AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-dms

I am working on a CDP Enablement project. We basically need to do reverse ETL to use the client's on-prem Postgres database as a source for Segment (https://segment.com/), but there is no direct integration between Postgres and Segment so the approach is to use Amazon S3 from AWS Lambda as a source connector. I am wondering if this is the best approach or if there are better ways to do it. I've been pointed towards Amazon DMS with ongoing replication, but the client doesn't want us to replicate their database for data governance reasons.

Someone else suggested we use a step function on a time trigger that uses a custom Glue job to retrieve data out the on-prem database and post to S3.

The loading of the database onto S3 should be a scheduled job because we will be sending this data to Segment as events. The data is highly transactional and we expect the frequency of loading to be every 10 minutes.

If anyone could point me in the best direction that'd be greatly appreciated. We are looking for the simplest and most cost-effective solution.

We initially thought of doing this using a lambda function that will connect to the on-prem database and migrate the data onto S3. I think this is way too complicated and there must be more straightforward ways.

Useful readings:
https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/cloud-apps/amazon-s3/